# Text Positioning all locations with position: absolute;

Tags: css, css-position

I'm trying to find a solution for positioning text inside a div at all the following locations:

Top Right

Top Left

Top Center

Middle (Center) Right

Middle (Center) Left

Middle (Center) center

Bottom Right

Bottom Left

Bottom Center

Since i wish to be able to position text only, and i don't want to use css property like valign because it is not supported by several browsers, then i searched online for possible solutions. I didn't have success with flex. Maybe don't know it well enough, but what i did manage to come up with is positioning via position: relative  and position: absolute;

However, I had success with some of the entire list of 9 combinations I wrote here. Would appriciate if anyone can complete the rest of the locations i failed to try and position, and if you know a better way or more simple one, which doesn't require position: absolute; => I would be more then happy to hear about it.

This is my code:

```
<head>
<meta content="en-us" http-equiv="Content-Language" />
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
<title>Untitled 1</title>
<style type="text/css">
.test {
    background-color: #C0C0C0;
    margin: 0px auto 0px auto;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}
.newStyle1 {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 0px;
}
.newStyle2 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    right: 0px;
}
.newStyle3 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
}
.newStyle4 {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    right: 0px;
}
.newStyle5 {
    margin: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-right: -50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="test">
    <span class="newStyle1">text</span> 
    <span class="newStyle2">text</span> 
    <span class="newStyle3">text</span> 
    <span class="newStyle4">text</span> 
    <span class="newStyle5">text</span> 
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Thank you.!

Comment: Note: the `<meta>` tag does not use or need a closing slash and never has. Also, the `type` attribute default is `text/css` so that isn't needed either. I removed your `valign` tag because `valign` is obsolete and that's an HTML attribute, not CSS.

Comment: @Rob, just to be clear as for the style. It should be like this: <style>..</style> ? not: <style type="..."> ?

Comment: Yes............

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<head>
    <meta content="en-us" http-equiv="Content-Language" />
    <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
    <title>Untitled 1</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        .test {
            background-color: #C0C0C0;
            margin: 0px auto 0px auto;
            width: 300px;
            height: 300px;
            overflow: hidden;
            position: relative;
            text-align: center;
        }

        .newStyle1 {
            position: absolute;
            bottom: 0px;
            left: 0px;
        }

        .newStyle2 {
            position: absolute;
            top: 0px;
            right: 0px;
        }

        .newStyle3 {
            position: absolute;
            top: 0px;
            left: 0px;
        }

        .newStyle4 {
            position: absolute;
            bottom: 0px;
            right: 0px;
        }

        .newStyle5 {
            margin: 0;
            position: absolute;
            top: 50%;
            left: 50%;
            transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        }

        .newStyle6 {
            margin: 0;
            position: absolute;
            top: 0px;
            left: 50%;
            transform: translate(-50%, 0);
        }

        .newStyle7 {
            margin: 0;
            position: absolute;
            bottom: 0px;
            left: 50%;
            transform: translate(-50%, 0);
        }

        .newStyle8 {
            margin: 0;
            position: absolute;
            top: 50%;
            left: 0px;
            transform: translate(0, -50%);
        }
        .newStyle9 {
            margin: 0;
            position: absolute;
            top: 50%;
            right: 0px;
            transform: translate(0, -50%);
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="test">
        <span class="newStyle1">text</span>
        <span class="newStyle2">text</span>
        <span class="newStyle3">text</span>
        <span class="newStyle4">text</span>
        <span class="newStyle5">text</span>
        <span class="newStyle6">text</span>
        <span class="newStyle7">text</span>
        <span class="newStyle8">text</span>
        <span class="newStyle9">text</span>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I'm speechless :) superb!.